# JSON API table to PHP echo

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I made an API CALL with Ecwid, and I got a JSON Response that works. However, this response sends me an Array that I can't find a way to use. I want to write something saying, " For each product in this JSON array, please show its name." This is what I have so far:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/83672989/products', [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer secret_XYZ',
    'accept' => 'application/json',
  ],
]);

echo $response->getBody(); 

foreach ($items in $response) {
    echo "sku";
}
```

My JSON Looks like :

```
{
    "total": 9,
    "count": 9,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 100,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 523184135,
            "sku": "0009",
            "thumbnailUrl": "https://d2j6dbq0eux0bg.cloudfront.net/images/83672989/3416888569.jpg",
            "unlimited": true,
            "inStock": true,
            "name": "EXEMPLE. Veste en jeans sans manches",
            "nameTranslated": {
                "fr": "EXEMPLE. Veste en jeans sans manches"
            },
            "price": 159.95,
            "priceInProductList": 160,
            "defaultDisplayedPrice": 160,
            "defaultDisplayedPriceFormatted": "Fr160",
            "costPrice": 0,
            "tax": {
                "taxable": true,
                "defaultLocationIncludedTaxRate": 0,
                "enabledManualTaxes": [],
                "taxClassCode": "default"
            },
```

I need to echo the SKU of items of this array in php for a WordPress page. I already tried a foreach loop on the json but it seems that I am not able to catch the data in JSON.

Comment: json_decode($response->getBody(), true) to have it in an array or "false" to have it as object

Comment: You first need to convert this string in to either an array or object by using json_decode as stated in SVGTA comment, json_decode takes a JSON.stringify string and convert it into a PHP array or object based on its second parameter like json_decode($JSON_str,true) where true is for Array and false for object (default false)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i managed showing the table, now i need to enter into items element any clue ? Can i try something like reponse[0] ?